How to differentiate a function whose integral domain depend on the variable?
I'd like to differentiate this function to find a local optimal solution:
$$
L(z) = | c(\textbf z) - \hat{c} | + \sum_{N}^{j} \int_{\Pi(\textbf z)} |c(z') - c_j(z')| \,dz'
$$

$z$ is a real variable
$c(z)$, $c_j(z)$ are differentiable and I know how to calculate their derivative
$\Pi(z)$ denotes a neighborhood of $z$, "arbitrarily large"

The obvious thing that is blocking me is the integral, whose domain depend on the variable I'm trying to optimize. Is there any technique for differentiating it?
If not differentiable, I would just throw in many $z$ and keep the one that minimizes $L(z)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

@AnneBauval This seems more complicated in higher dimensions. OP: Could you give us more context on what exactly $\Pi(\mathbf{z})$ is?

@FShrike This seems to be in dimension $1$: $z$ is a real variable and $c$ is a function of $z$. OP: why \mathbb in front of your second and third $z$, and not in front of the 1st one?

It seems to me that you need more constraints on the map $z\mapsto \Pi(z)$. Assume $F_j(z')$ is the antiderivative of $|c(z')-c_j(z')|$ and $a(z),b(z)$ are the endpoints of the interval $\Pi(z)$ (assuming it's an interval) then you need to diff. $F_j(b(z))-F_j(a(z))$ unless $F_j$ is constant, if $z\mapsto a(z),b(z)$ is very "unsmooth", there should be no way this is differentiable in any sense. If they are smooth you, can use the chainrule.

Yes, I think this is solvable with the Leibniz rule as @AnneBauval hinted me.
However it gives me another integral, that is not easily computable for doing gradient descent. I'm going for the "try many z and keep the best" approach.
